# How to replace segment object length with decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

In the following TikZ example I would like to replace the usage of snakes with decorations. How can I adjust the `segment object length` with decorations?

```
\documentclass[tikz, preview=true]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzstyle{radiowave old}=[snake=waves,
                           segment length=1mm,
                           segment object length=4mm,
                           segment angle=30
                         ]

\tikzstyle{radiowave new}=[decorate, 
                       decoration={waves,
                         segment length=1mm,
                         %segment object length=4mm, <- not available
                         angle=30}
                      ]

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}                         
    \draw[radiowave old] (-1,1) to node[left,pos=0] {old} (1,-1);                     
    \draw[radiowave new] (-1,-1) to node[right,pos=1] {new} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ example with waves]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is called `radius`.  I also converted your usage of the deprecated `\tikzstyle` to the modern `\tikzset`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, preview=true]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  radiowave old/.style={
    snake=waves,
    segment length=1mm,
    segment object length=4mm,
    segment angle=30
  },
  radiowave new/.style={
    decorate, 
    decoration={
      waves,
      segment length=1mm,
      radius=4mm,
      angle=30
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}                         
  \draw[radiowave old] (-1,1) to node[left,pos=0] {old} (1,-1);                     
  \draw[radiowave new] (-1,-1) to node[right,pos=1] {new} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: enter code here]